# Object Controlling using Arduino

Tags: node-editor, objects, game-engine

I am working on my project for haptics. For this purpose, the task is to create a virtual finger and control its movement using Arduino. The problem now is that I am using Blender 2.80 and the cannot find a way to **control the object's movement using a Controller.**

***The idea was to get the input from the sensors and import the serial data from the Arduino to python and use his data for controlling in Blender***.

I imported the data from Arduino to python but can't find a way for further process. the example I saw used the blender gaming engine, but I used blender rather than the gaming engine.

One more thing to ask

**Can we control ojects movement in blender 2.80 or we must use a gaming engine for this purpose ??**

Need guidance in both these problems.

Comment: Hi,  Syed Taha, there is no more game engine in Blender since version 2.80. Could you post the code you already have? What do you want to control and how? Please use the edit link and provide more context and detail to your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this in real-time, I would investigate using UDP sockets, as they're fast and cheap.

As a test I created a modal operator who was on a timer and listened on a socket on each cycle.

[image: example]

Unfortunately, my modal operator arbitrarily appears to just stop. But as a quick test, this looks promising.

---

Create a cube. Start this python client (who sends random data).

```
import socket
import random
import time

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5006

print("UDP target IP:", UDP_IP)
print("UDP target port:", UDP_PORT)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.connect((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))


for i in range(1000):
    time.sleep(0.02)
    MESSAGE = str(random.randint(0, 5))
    sock.send(MESSAGE.encode())
    print(MESSAGE)
```

And run this modal operator in Blender.

```
import bpy
import socket

class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

    def modal (self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'ESC':
            context.window_manager.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER_REPORT':
            try:
                data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
                self.cube.location.x = float(data)
            except:
                # timed out
                pass

        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.2)
        return {"PASS_THROUGH"}


    def execute(self, context):
        self.cube = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

        print("creating socket")
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5006))
        self.sock.settimeout(0.18)

        print("adding timer")
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.2)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}


bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)

bpy.ops.object.modal_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```